# How do I Convert an array of object into single object after grouping in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of below objects

```
[
  {
    "date": "2021-07-24",
    "model": "Benz",
    "bookings": 3
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-24",
    "model": "BMW",
    "bookings": 4
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-24",
    "model": "Audi",
    "bookings": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-25",
    "model": "Benz",
    "bookings": 5
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-25",
    "model": "BMW",
    "bookings": 7
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-25",
    "model": "Audi",
    "bookings": 3
  }
]
```

How do I convert the same after grouping as the below one in js?

Expected:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2021-07-24",
    "Benz": 3,
    "BMW": 4,
    "Audi": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-07-25",
    "Benz": 5,
    "BMW": 7,
    "Audi": 3
  }
]
```

Idea on implementing it would be much helpful.
Tried implementing a different approach of grouping as referred  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

But the above case mentioned as expected output suits the purpose well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce() with a Map object.

Edit:

`data.reduce()` will return a `Map` Object and you can use `.values()` to get the values of the Map object.

Then you can use the spread operator `...` to get the values of `Map` object in an array.

In short:

```js
const output = [...data.reduce().values()]
```

**Example below:**

```js
const data = [ { date: "2021-07-24", model: "Benz", bookings: 3, }, { date: "2021-07-24", model: "BMW", bookings: 4, }, { date: "2021-07-24", model: "Audi", bookings: 1, }, { date: "2021-07-25", model: "Benz", bookings: 5, }, { date: "2021-07-25", model: "BMW", bookings: 7, }, { date: "2021-07-25", model: "Audi", bookings: 3, }, ];

const o = [
  ...data
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      if (a.has(b.date)) {
        const obj = a.get(b.date);
        if (obj[b.model]) {
          obj[b.model] += b.bookings;
        } else {
          obj[b.model] = b.bookings;
        }
        a.set(b.date, obj);
      } else {
        a.set(b.date, { date: b.date, [b.model]: b.bookings });
      }
      return a;
    }, new Map())
    .values(),
];

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Great.
Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: @CodeWiz, I updated the answer with some explanations.

Comment: @CodeWiz, I updated my answer. I remove some unnecessary `...` spread operator in the reduce().

Comment: That's great. Thanks for updating it